# Kotlin flow inside flow, the parent flow does not call collect

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Recently I discovered a flow behaviour that I couldn't understand.

## The Problem Description

Consider this situation:
you have a parent `flow` and inside its `collect`, you'll have a "child" `flow` and calling `.collect()`, like this:

```
parentFlow.collect {
    childFlow.collect()
}
```

Then if the parentFlow emits some values, the `childFlow.collect()` will not be called.

## What I have tried

By doing some searches on SO I found the following questions are similar to mine:

1. [Android: collecting a Kotlin Flow inside another not emitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65570284/android-collecting-a-kotlin-flow-inside-another-not-emitting)
2. [Chaining Flows (collecting a Flow within the collect{} block of another Flow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68873104/chaining-flows-collecting-a-flow-within-the-collect-block-of-another-flow)

However I intend to dig deeper about what's the reason behind this behaviour, therefore I have created a project to reliably reproduce it, you can check it out on github:
https://github.com/dumbfingers/Playground/tree/flow-inside-flow

In this mini-repro, I have put some log output. When you click the button, the expect log output should be:

```
Test: onArrayUpdated
Test: item: {some number}
Test: item: {some number}
Test: onFlowChanged
Test: repoObserve delayed
Test: item: {some number}
Test: item: {some number}
Test: repoAnotherObserve delayed
```

However, the actual result is:

```
Test: onArrayUpdated
Test: item: {some number}
Test: item: {some number}
```

Which indicates these two `collect` call inside the `randomFlow` are not called:

```
      repository.repoObserve(list).collect {
            repository.repoAnotherObserve().collect()
        }
```

## Question

In this SO: [Android: collecting a Kotlin Flow inside another not emitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65570284/android-collecting-a-kotlin-flow-inside-another-not-emitting)
The answer suggested that "collecting infinite flow" cause this issue.

And in my experiment, either

- changing `repoObserve` and `repoAnotherObserve` to `suspend` method and making them not returning a flow

or

- use `combine` to combine these flows

will solve this problem.

But why does collect flow inside another flow's collect won't work?

Comment: Can you reproduce outside of Android? This example repo seems very big for such a simple repro

Comment: `repoObserve` and `repoAnotherObserve` return flows that never emit anything. I think you might be confusing `Flow` with suspending functions. Flows like this should be called nonetheless, but I don't think this makes any sense as written

Answer (score 2):

You can launch a Coroutine inside parent collect { ... } block

```kotlin
val scope: CoroutineScope = ...
parentFlow.collect {
    scope.launch {
        childFlow.collect()
    }
}
```

or

```kotlin
parentFlow.flatMapMerge { childFlow }.collect {
    // logic here ...
}
```

You can also replace `flatMapMerge` with `flatMapLatest`/`flatMapConcat`/[`flatMapFirst`](https://hoc081098.github.io/FlowExt/docs/0.x/-flow-ext/com.hoc081098.flowext/flat-map-first.html) ([FlowExt](https://github.com/hoc081098/FlowExt) library)

Hope to help you

Comment: Tried both and they work for me, thx very much. Going to look up flatMapMerge too.

Answer (score 0):

Your click listener generates the exact same array list of two numbers each time it’s clicked because you are using a new Random instance with the same seed value of 10 each time. You’re passing them to a StateFlow, and StateFlows have the same behavior as `distinctUntilChanged()`. They won’t emit a value that is equal to the last emitted value.

I think if you remove the parameter from your Random constructor call, you will get your expected output. This is because your innermost-called flow is not infinite like in the questions you linked.